# Roots of matrices in $G_2(Z)$

Tags: matrices, lie-groups

Let $G_2$ denote the exceptional Lie group $G_2$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebraic group. Suppose that is also given a matrix representation $\rho : G_2\rightarrow SO(7)$. Let $M$ be a matrix with integral coefficients in the image of this representation. What would be an approach to prove that there is no $S$, with integral coefficients, in the image of this representation, such that $M=S^k$. My first attempt was to use jordan decomposition $M = M_s\cdot M_u$ and reduce to the semi-simple case, but that didn't work. Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: When you say "matrix in $G_2$", do you have a specific representation of $G_2$ in mind? I ask because I'm not sure I know how to answer the question already for $SL_n$, much less $G_2$.

Comment: To reinforce Allen's comment, I'd also request a more precise statement.  What exactly is meant by $G_2(Z)$, and what are "integral matrices" in $G_2$ other than elements of $G_2(Z)$?

Comment: @AllenKnutson  I'm sorry for the confusing question,  I've clarified it now. Thanks.

Comment: @JimHumphreys  I'm sorry for the confusing question, I've clarified it now. Thanks.